# Flash warning when creating PDF portfolio

Tags: flash, pdf, acrobat, portfolio

I'm trying to create a PDF portfolio out of several PDF files - these are just plain vector graphics printed to PDF form Ai CS6. My Adobe Acrobat X Pro whines about flash player content and points me to a Flash distribution page.

Why is it so? Why do I need to fight with Flash if I don't have and Flash content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe Acrobat creates a Flash based navigator for the files in the portfolio. Probably the Flash version you have installed on the machine is old and you need a newer version in order to view the portfolio content.